# Reading Xml file contents to a class instance in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a class like

```
class CXmlData
    {
        String Data1="";
        String Data2="";
        List<String> lst=new List<String>()
    }
```

and a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<String,CXmlData> dict=new Dictionary<String,CXmlData>();
```

The xml file is having the following structure

```
<Root>
    <ChildList>
        <Children>
            <Child Name="a1" val="A"/>
            <Child Name="a2" val="A"/>
            <Child Name="b1" val="B"/>
            <Child Name="c1" val="C"/>
            <Child Name="c2" val="C"/>
        </Childen>
        <Siblings_One>
              <Sibling Name="A" Xpos="0" Ypos=""/>
              <Sibling Name="B" Xpos="1" Ypos="1"/>
        </Sibling_One>
        <Siblings_Two>
              <Sibling Name="C" Xpos="0" Ypos="0"/>              
        </Sibling_Two>
    </ChildList>
</Root>
```

i need to read the data from the above xml file and to add to the dictionary

so the Resulting Dictionary will be like

```
    Key(String)          Value(Instance of CXmlData)

        "A"                   Data1="0"
                           Data2="2"
                              lst=new List<String>{"a1","a2"}

        "B"                   Data1="1" 
                              Data2="1"
                              lst=new List<String>{"b1"}

        "C"                   Data1="0"
                              Data2="2"
                              lst=new List<String>{"c1","c2"}
```

(if Xpos value is "0" then Data2(Ypos) value should be "2")
Now I'm using like

**1**.Read Sibling_One child values

if Xpos value is "0" the take Ypos value as"2"

else keep the same

**2**.Read Sibling_Two child values

if Xpos value is "0" the take Ypos value as"2"

else keep the same

**3**.Read Children->Child values

Compare Sibling->Name attribute ==Child->Name

if matches then add the Child->Name attribute value to the list

i'm using Xml Namespace(System.Xml) and foreach loop for this, but its taking more time to complete the process

**EDIT** Sample Code

```
            XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\foo.xml");
            XmlElement XRoot = XDoc.DocumentElement;
            List<string> TempList = new List<string>();
            XmlNodeList XChildName = XDoc.SelectNodes("//ChildList/Sibling_One/Sibling");
            foreach (XmlNode ch in XChildName)
            {
                TempList .Add(ch.Attributes["Name"].Value);
                CXmlData P = new CXmlData();
                if (ch.Attributes["Xpos"].Value == "0")
                    P.Data2 = "2";
                else
                    P.Data2 = ch.Attributes["Ypos"].Value;
                P.Data1 = ch.Attributes["Xpos"].Value;
                dict.Add(ch.Attributes["NetName"].Value, P);

            }
            XChildName = XDoc.SelectNodes("//ChildList/Sibling_Two/Sibling");
            foreach (XmlNode ch in XChildName)
            {
                TempList .Add(ch.Attributes["Name"].Value);
                CXmlData P = new CXmlData();
                if (ch.Attributes["Xpos"].Value == "0")
                    P.Data2 = "2";
                else
                    P.Data2 = ch.Attributes["Ypos"].Value;
                P.Data1 = ch.Attributes["Xpos"].Value;
                dict.Add(ch.Attributes["Name"].Value, P);
            }

            foreach (string str in TempList )
            {
                List<String> lstChildValues = (from XmlNode xn in XDoc.SelectNodes("//ChildList/Children/Child")
                            where xn.Attributes["val"].Value == str
                            select xn.Attributes["Name"].Value).ToList();

                if (dict.Keys.Contains(str))
                {

                    CXmlData p = dict[str];
                    dict.Remove(str);
                    p.lst = lstChildValues;
                    dict.Add(str, p);
                }
            }
```

is there any way to do this using LINQ to Xml (System.xml.Linq)?

Comment: This is not clear. Please read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints Please include what you are currently trying, and in what way it is not working (what you expect *and* what you get).

Comment: You should edit `CXmlData` so that the variable names are actually meaningful. Data1, Data2 and lst provide no indication of what the variables are actually holding and it's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<String>l_lstName = XDocument.Load("foo.xml")
                               .Descendants("Sibling")
                               .Select(Temp => Temp.Attribute("Name").Value).ToList();


        Dictionary<String, CXmlData> dict = new Dictionary<string, CXmlData>();





        dict = XDocument.Load("foo.xml")
                               .Descendants("Sibling").ToDictionary(
                               X => X.Attribute("Name").Value,
                               X => new CXmlData
                               {
                                   lst =XDocument.Load("foo.xml").Descendants("Children").Descendants("Child").Where(Temp=>Temp.Attribute("val").Value==X.Attribute("Name").Value).Select(Temp=>Temp.Attribute("Name").Value).ToList(),
                                   Data1 = X.Attribute("Xpos").Value == "0" ? "2" : X.Attribute("Ypos").Value,
                                   Data2 = X.Attribute("Xpos").Value
                               }
                               );
```